# Rails file upload error "undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, upload

i have simple upload form:

```
<%= form_for(:product, :url => {:action => 'update_product', :id => @product.id}, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
<%= f.file_field(:product_image) %>
<%= submit_tag('Upload') %>
<% end %>
```

And in a controller:

```
def update_product
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if(product)
        uploaded_image = params[:product][:product_image]
        params[:product][:product_image] = uploaded_image.original_filename
        product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated!"
        redirect_to :action => 'edit_product', :id => product.id
    end
end
```

When i try to upload, i have an error "undefined method `original_filename' for nil:NilClass"
What i'm doing wrong?

I use Rails 3.0.10 and Ruby 1.9.2p290

Answer (score 1):

My guess is params[:product][:product_image] is nil.

Try to use gem for file uploads.

Sources

[1.Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip)

[2.Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this symptom, but intermittently. Sometimes the browser (chrome) seems not to select the file from the 'Choose File' dialogue box. On one occasion I saw that after double-clicking a file in the dialogue box it took several seconds to show as the selected file back in the browser window. I guess if you hit 'submit' before the files is effectively selected then you'll get that error.

```
     <h2>Choose file to upload ...</h2>
<%= form_tag({:action => :sched_file_uploader}, :multipart => true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag 'schedfile' %>
  </br></br>
  <%= text_area_tag(:file_info, "<care to say anything about this file?>", :size => "24x6") %>
  </br></br>
  <input name="upload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

please remove this line:

```
params[:product][:product_image] = uploaded_image.original_filename

def update_product
    product = Product.find(params[:id])
    if(product)
        uploaded_image = params[:product][:product_image].original_filename
        product.update_attributes(params[:product])
        flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated!"
        redirect_to :action => 'edit_product', :id => product.id
    end
end
```